# .Net Observer Pattern changes. When did these happen and why?

Tags: c#, .net, observer-pattern

I was just trying to explain the Observer pattern to a colleague for use in a C# application. I remarked that is should be easy enough to implement by looking up some MSDN documentation. However, I was surprised to find that the MSDN example deviates from how I've been taught the Observer pattern. Mind you, I've primarily used the pattern in Java, but I was under the impression that the .Net implementation was pretty much the same.

The pattern I know uses the methods Notify, Subscribe and Unsubscribe. This new implementation explained on MSDN uses OnNext, OnCompleted, OnError and Subscribe. I'm able to find articles from just a few years ago explaining the Notify version of it, however.

At first glance, this new version seems unnecessarily convoluted and it has me slightly confused. Since when has this implementation been around, and why was it implemented this way? Wat are the advantages?

Answer (score 3):

Bear in mind that the .NET Observer interfaces are closely related to the MS [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609).  If you want to understand the added functionality provided by OnError/OnCompleted, this is probably the best place to research.  The rest of the pattern pretty much matches as-is:

1. Subscribe is still just Subscribe.
2. Unsubscribe is intended to be implemented through Disposal of a context returned by Subscribe.
3. OnNext corresponds to Notify.

So really the only new functionality is OnError (providing a parallel error-reporting channel to let the observer know that the observable has entered an error state) and OnCompleted (to let the observer know that the observable won't be providing any more messages.)  You could accomplish this with details in the message to indicate these state transitions, but having them baked-in makes sense if you think of an observable as a sort of message channel which can undergo state changes that are somewhat orthogonal to the intention of the messages themselves.

Answer (score 1):

The four interfaces to look at are the following.

```
IEnumerable<T>
    IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()

IEnumerator<T>
    bool MoveNext()
    T Current { get; }
    void Dispose()

IObservable<T>
    IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<T>)

IObserver<T>
    void OnNext(T)
    void OnError(Exception)
    void OnCompleted()
```

The `IEnumerable<T>` and `IObservable<T>` interfaces are *duals*. Same goes for `IEnumerator<T>` and `IObserver<T>`. The *interactive* interfaces, `IEnumerable<T>` and `IEnumerator<T>`, use *pull* semantics to describe a sequence of `T`s.  The *reactive* interfaces, `IObservable<T>` and `IObserver<T>`, use *push* semantics to describe a sequence of `T`s.

Suppose I have an `IEnumerator<T>` named `e`.  When I call `e.MoveNext()` followed by `e.Current` in the case of success, I am conceptually getting one of three things:

- `e.MoveNext()` returns `true` and I get a `T`
- `e.MoveNext()` throws an `Exception`
- `e.MoveNext()` returns `false` and I have completion

Notice how these correspond exactly to the `IObserver<T>` methods `OnNext`, `OnError`, `OnCompleted`. The difference is in the `IEnumerator<T>` case I *pull* out information but in the `IObserver<T>` case I *push* in information.

When I call `IEnumerator<T>.Dispose`, the sequence of `T`s is canceled. Similarly, when I call `Dispose`on the `IDisposable` returned by `IObservable<T>.Subscribe`, the sequence of `T`s is canceled.

When I call `IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator` I *pull* out an `IEnumerator<T>`. When I call `IObservable<T>.Subscribe` I *push* in an `IObserver<T>`.